# How can i create FHIR ValueSet with hierarchical content?

Tags: hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir

I want create ValueSet with link to my CodeSystem.
ValueSet expantion with enclosed contains should be like:

```
{
    ...
    "expansion": {
        "parameter": [
            {
                "name": "total",
                "valueString": "282"
            }
        ],
        "contains": [
            {
                "code": "0",
                "display": "asd",
                "contains": [
                    {
                        "code": "High"
                    },
                    {
                        "code": "Okso",
                        "display": "1"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
    ...
}
```

I tried to create CodeSystem with hierarchical concepts, and ValueSet with compose.include to my CodeSystem. But i getted expantion with 1 level contents like this:

```
"contains": [
    {
        "code": "0",
        "display": "asd"
    }, { 
        "code": "High"
    }, {
        "code": "Okso",
        "display": "1"
    }
]
```

I tried change different attributes CodeSystem, but this bring me no result.
Help me please with a simple example!